# How to get the values in QModelIndexList in qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

I have a `QTableView` that enables `MultiSelection` selectionMode following a `SelectRows` behavior as follow:

```
QSqlQueryModel model = db_manager->get_all();
ui->tableView->setModel(model);
ui->tableView->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
ui->tableView->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::MultiSelection);
ui->tableView->show();
```

The selection is working properly before which the indexes of theses selected rows are put into `QModelIndexList` as follow:

```
selectedRowsIndexesList = ui->tableView->selectionModel()->selectedRows();
```

Now I need to extract the information where these indexes are pointing to. I do this at the moment manually as follow:

```
qDebug() << model->index(0,0).data().toString();
```

I change the first "0" manually. But I need to automate the process through a for-loop statement like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < selectedRowsIndexesList.size(); i++){
        qDebug() << model->index(??,0).data().toString();
    }
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already have the indexes in a list, so why go back to the model?
You can simply access the data using the indexes you've stored:

```
for (int i = 0; i < selectedRowsIndexesList.size(); i++){
        qDebug() << selectedRowsIndexesList[i].data().toString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Why ? because I didn't know what to do and how to invoke the stored indexes. Honestly, I panicked, and totally forgot that `selectedRowsIndexesList` is an `Array`.

Answer (score 0):

The `QModelIndexList` is just a typedef as per the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmodelindex.html#QModelIndexList-typedef). It is just a synonym for `QList<QModelIndex>` and you can iterate through the indexes as you would do through any `QList` variables.

```
for(int i = 0; i < mindex_list.size(); i++)
    qDebug() << mindex_list.at(i).toString();
```

Or something similar.